# Excel VBA for creating numbered list in Word

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, office-2007

I am trying to use VBA code in Excel to create a numbered list in a Word document.

```
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document

Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrdApp.Visible = True
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add

With wrdDoc
    For i = 0 To 5
        .Content.InsertAfter ("Paragraph " & i)
        .Content.InsertParagraphAfter
    Next

    .Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
        ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:= _
        False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:= _
        wdWord10ListBehavior
End With

Set wrdApp = Nothing
Set wrdDoc = Nothing
```

When I run this I get an error:

> Method 'ApplyListTemplateWithLevel' of object 'ListFormat' failed

I have checked the `Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library` in the Excel VBA references list.

Comment: I tested the code in Excel 2010 for Word 2010. it works perfectly... Testing it on 2007

Comment: Damn! My Vista on VMWare is configuring updates. Will take sometime before I can test the above...

Comment: Finally tested it in Office 2007. It is working just fine.

Comment: OK thanks, still not working for me so will wait to see if anyone else has any ideas.

Comment: what happens if you add the line `DoEvents` for the line which is causing the error?

Comment: Ok Found what the problem is.. I guess :) Posting an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I found the problem. I remoted into a friends machine to check. I got the same error as you if there were other word documents open. If no other word documents are open then your code just works fine.

Try this code. It latebinds with the Word Application so you don't need a reference to be added.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oWordApp As Object, oWordDoc As Object

    '~~> Establish an Word application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    oWordApp.Visible = True

    Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Add

    With oWordDoc
        For i = 0 To 5
            .Content.InsertAfter ("Paragraph " & i)
            .Content.InsertParagraphAfter
        Next

        DoEvents

        .Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
        ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:= _
        False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:= _
        wdWord10ListBehavior
    End With

    Set oWordApp = Nothing
    Set oWordDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```