# VBA/Word add bullets, numbering etc

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have been playing with VBA code that permits automatic creation of word documents.  In the example below, I write a Word paragraph 6 times.  In order to do certain formatting (bullets, numbering, putting text in tables etc...) it appears necessary to make a second pass and apply formatting after text is created.  Can this be done in a single pass like VBA allows us to do with bold or italics?

Example:
- toggle numbering 
- write line

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim oWordApp As Object, oWordDoc As Object
    Dim i As Integer


    '~~> Establish an Word application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oWordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    oWordApp.Visible = True

    Set oWordDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Add

    With oWordDoc
        For i = 0 To 5
            .Content.InsertAfter ("Paragraph " & i)
            .Content.InsertParagraphAfter
        Next

        ' Yields execution so that the operating system can process other events.
        DoEvents

        ' why does this have to be done after creating text? 
        .Paragraphs(1).Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
        ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:= _
        False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:= _
        wdWord10ListBehavior

        .Paragraphs(2).Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
        ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:= _
        False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:= _
        wdWord10ListBehavior

    End With

    Set oWordApp = Nothing
    Set oWordDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

example from [Excel VBA for creating numbered list in Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329871/excel-vba-for-creating-numbered-list-in-word?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obviously do it. There are few possibilities but I believe the below solution give you a clue of how to use `Document.Range(start,end)` property.

```
 With oWordDoc
        For i = 0 To 5
            .Content.InsertAfter ("Paragraph " & i)
            .Content.InsertParagraphAfter
        Next

        ' Yields execution so that the operating system can process other events.
        DoEvents

 'apply numbering for 6 added paragraphs
   .Range(.Paragraphs(1).Range.Start, _
                .Paragraphs(6).Range.End) _
        .ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel ListTemplate:= _
        ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:= _
        False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:= _
        wdWord10ListBehavior

'... the rest of your code here
```

Comment: will gives it a try, but I would really like to do something like 1)set style to "header 1" 2) write header 3) new paragraph 4) set paragraph to bullet list (or numbered list) 5) write paragraph ... repeat 6) write n paragraphs ... then repeat

Comment: I am not happy with writing paragraphs (then adding formatting afterwards. Paragraphs come from another database source and may number in the hudreds per ducument.

Answer (score 2):

I had some trouble adding bullets, so here is the code that worked for me.

Note that this requires adding a reference to `Microsoft Word 15.0 Object Library`

```
Sub Generate()
Dim objWord
Dim objDoc
Dim temp3 As Word.ListTemplate
Dim objSelection
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
objWord.Visible = True
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

'Change your text here:
objSelection.TypeText ("This is my text in Word Document using Excel")
objSelection.TypeParagraph
objSelection.TypeText ("Here is more text")
'--------------------------

Set temp3 = objWord.ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1)
With temp3.ListLevels(1)
    .Font.Name = "Symbol"
    .Font.Size = 11
    .NumberFormat = ChrW(61623)
    .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
    .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
    .NumberPosition = objWord.CentimetersToPoints(0.63)
    .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
    .TextPosition = objWord.CentimetersToPoints(1.27)
    .TabPosition = wdUndefined
    .StartAt = 1
End With

'Apply formatting to our range
objDoc.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate ListTemplate:=temp3
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do it...

```
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application


    With wdApp
        .Visible = True
        .Activate
        .Documents.Add
        ' turn on bullets
        .ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1).Name = ""
        .Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate ListTemplate:=.ListGalleries(wdBulletGallery).ListTemplates(1), _
            continuepreviouslist:=False, applyto:=wdListApplyToWholeList, defaultlistbehavior:=wdWord9ListBehavior

        With .Selection
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
            .Font.Bold = False
            .Font.Name = "Century Gothic"
            .Font.Size = 12
            .TypeText ("some details")
            .TypeParagraph
            .TypeText ("some details")
            .TypeParagraph
        End With

        ' turn off bullets
        .Selection.Range.ListFormat.RemoveNumbers wdBulletGallery

        With .Selection
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
            .TypeText ("some details")
            .TypeParagraph
            .TypeText ("some details")
            .TypeParagraph

        End With

        ' turn on outline numbers
        .ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).Name = ""
        .Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate ListTemplate:=.ListGalleries(wdOutlineNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), _
            continuepreviouslist:=False, applyto:=wdListApplyToWholeList, defaultlistbehavior:=wdWord9ListBehavior

        With .Selection
            .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
            .TypeText ("some details")
            .TypeParagraph
            .TypeText ("some details")

        End With

    End With
```

Comment: Added the listgalleries and Selection.range to turn on bullets and the RemoveNumbers to remove bullets afterwards.  Worked perfectly in my code.  Thanks